# How to use DateTime.Parse() method both side (i.e in expression left and expression right ) while creating expression tree?

Tags: linq, expression-trees

```
lstReport=lstReport.Where(o=>DateTime.Parse(o.Field)==DateTime.Parse(o.FieldValue));
//I am creating above statement dynamically like this 
var variable = Expression.Variable(typeof(Report));
foreach (SQWFilterConstraint oFC in oFilter.LstFilterConstraint) //using this collection I am making dynamic query
{
    Expression  ExprLeft =Expression.Property(variable, oFC.Field);
    MethodInfo methodDateTimeParse = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("Parse", newType[] { typeof(string) });
    var methodParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), oFC.FieldValue);
    Expression exprRight = Expression.Call(methodDateTimeParse, methodParam ); //This is working fine for right side
}
var props = new[] { variable };
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Report, bool>>(ExprPrev, props).Compile();
ReportList = ReportList.Where(lambda).ToList();
```

So I need to apply the `DateTime.Parse` method on field also which comes at the left side (which is underlined and bold above left side of the operator)

Comment: Why don't you do exactly the same thing you already do for the right side?

Comment: I tried but it's not working ,because I dont how to supply parameter  var methodParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string),oFC.FieldName);// this function expect constant value as second parameter not fieldname

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you trying to achieve.

1) What's the foreach for? Each property that has to be compared?

2) ExprPrev was never declared.

Anyhow, the way to create that expression is as follows.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestDateTimeParse()
        {
            var variable = Expression.Variable(typeof (Report));

            var parseMethodInfo = typeof (DateTime).GetMethod("Parse", new[] {typeof (string)});
            var left = Expression.Call(parseMethodInfo, Expression.Property(variable, "Field"));
            var right = Expression.Call(parseMethodInfo, Expression.Property(variable, "FieldValue"));
            var equals = Expression.Equal(left, right);

            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Report, bool>>(equals, variable).Compile();

            var target = new Report {Field = DateTime.Now.ToString()};
            target.FieldValue = target.Field;
            expression(target).Should().Be.True();
        }

        public class Report
        {
            public string Field { get; set; }
            public string FieldValue { get; set; }
        }
```